# Открыть url адрес в проводнике

Tags: c#

Нужно открыть в файловом проводнике Url адрес SharePoint

Я делаю так

```
  Process.Start("explorer", @"http://....");
```

Но открывается браузер. А мне нужно чтобы открылся именно!!! проводник.
и именно по такому адресу.
Да я понимаю что это не файловый путь и если задать файловый путь то откроется как нужно.
но есть нюансы связанные с админами с которыми трудно договорится. И работает что нужно только через URL.

Если ручками в проводнике ввести url адрес то работает как нужно внутри нашей корпоративной сети.

В общем как заставить открыть именно проводник из C#?

Спасибо.

Comment: Вроде как проводник умеет открывать `ftp`  (не точно)

Comment: ftp не подходит к сожалению.

Comment: и что должен отображать проводник по пути http://...?

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался

нужно в пути использовать DavWWWRoot
Особенность share point
тогда можно использовать как файловый путь

Подробнее...
Если использовать `http://sharepoint/myfolder` путь то программа открывает браузер. если использовать путь как к каталогу файлов то я не получаю результат(список файлов в каталоге). Если в пути сказать `\\sharepoint\DavWWWRoot\myfolder` все открывается. Это видимо служебное слово в sharepoint которое говорит и что-то делает по другому. Я не админ не разбираюсь как работает sharepoint. Это слово DavWWWRoot можно нагуглить. Мне все-таки админы подсказали этот выход

Comment: Напишите как именно вы сделали

Comment: Если использовать http:\\sharepoint\myfolder путь  то программ открывает браузер. если использовать путь файла то я не получаю результат(список файлов в каталоге). Если в пути сказать \\sharepoint\DavWWWRoot\myfolder все открывается. Это видима служебное слово в sharepoint которое говорит что то делает по другому. Я не админ не разбираюсь как работает sharepoint. Это слово DavWWWRoot можно нагуглить.  Мне все-таки админы подсказали этот выход.

Comment: @Manul74 Здравствуйте. Отредактируйте ваш ответ на вопрос, вставив в него эту информацию из комментария. Так же, не забудь поставить галочку, когда появится такая возможно, гласящую о том, что выбранный ответ помогает с решение проблемы